# org.hibernate.QueryException: Expected positional parameter count: 1, actual parameters: [] [CALL GET_ALL_ITEM_TYPE(?)]

Tags: java, hibernate

**Procedure**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_ALL_ITEM_TYPE 
(
    cur_OUT OUT SYS_REFCURSOR 
    )    
AS 
BEGIN
 OPEN cur_OUT FOR 
 SELECT * FROM PG_ITEM_TYPE ;
END GET_ALL_ITEM_TYPE;
```

**Model Class**

```
@NamedNativeQueries({

    @NamedNativeQuery(
            name = "getAllItemType",
            query = "CALL GET_ALL_ITEM_TYPE(?)",
            resultClass = GdItemType.class
            )
})
```

**DAO**

```
@Override
    public List<GdItemType> getAllGdItemType() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query =  session.getNamedQuery("getAllItemType");
        List<GdItemType> result = query.list();
        return result;

    }
```

I am getting error Expected positional parameter count: 1, actual parameters: [] [CALL GET_ALL_ITEM_TYPE(?)].
I can't understand whats the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stored procedure has an output parameter, and the mapping contains a reference to it. As a result, Hibernate expects the parameter to be supplied.

You could try adding a Hibernate query hint

```
@javax.persistence.QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.callable", value = "true") }
```

or changing the stored procedure mapping to

```
@NamedNativeQueries({

    @NamedNativeQuery(
            name = "getAllItemType",
            query = "? = CALL GET_ALL_ITEM_TYPE()",
            resultClass = GdItemType.class
            )
})
```

Comment: I changed the stored procedure mapping but still getting the error .Then 
I have added query hint but now getting another error ....org.hibernate.HibernateException: Problem while trying to load or access OracleTypes.CURSOR value@Peter G. Horvath

Comment: That might be because the Hibernate Oracle Dialect tries to access something from the JDBC driver, which is not present in that JDBC driver version you have. You have to find the correct driver and dialect combination. I would suggest trying the latest JDBC driver first. If the problem persist, then you might have to explicitly set, which Oracle Dialect version Hibernate should use.